# emberjs (1.0rc1) nested routes but render default child route when at parent

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing, ember-router

I have an ember app with a home page showing two links: 'sign in' and 'request invite'.

Each link goes to a nested route under the parent (`index`) route, rendering into the `{{outlet}}` of the `index` route. It is working like so:

- `/`: renders `index` into application outlet
- `/sign_in`: renders index stuff then renders `index/sign_in` into index template's outlet
- `/request_invite`: renders index stuff then renders `index/request_invite` into index template's outlet

This works fine, but what I'd like to do is have the 'sign in' template rendered into the `index` outlet by default. So the first bullet above would change to be like so:

- `/`: renders `index` into the `{{outlet}}` *and* renders `index/sign_in` into index template's outlet

**templates**

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <h1>application</h1>
  {{#linkTo "index"}}index{{/linkTo}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='index'>
  <h2>index</h2>
  {{#linkTo "index.sign_in"}}Sign in{{/linkTo}}
  |
  {{#linkTo "index.request_invite"}}Request Invite{{/linkTo}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='index/sign_in'>
  <h3>index/sign_in</h3>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='index/request_invite'>
  <h3>index/request_invite</h3>
</script>
```

**routes**

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("index", function() {
    this.route("sign_in");
    this.route("request_invite");
  });
});
```

Here is a [jsbin with the above code](http://jsbin.com/isodas/3/edit).

When it first loads it doesn't display the `index/sign_in` or `index/request_invite` template. I'd to show that `index/sign_in` template by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could declare the IndexRoute explicitly and implement the [redirect hook:](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/)

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect : function(){
    this.transitionTo("index.sign_in");
  }
});
```

**Update: Using a Route other named then index ([JS Bin Link](http://jsbin.com/isodas/9/edit))**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("main", function() {
    this.route("sign_in");
    this.route("request_invite");
  });
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect : function(){
    this.transitionTo("main");
  }
})
App.MainIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect : function(){
    this.transitionTo("main.sign_in");
  }
});
```

Comment: If I do this, it does not render the index template into the application outlet. Here's a fiddle -- it should have the "sign in | request invite" links but does not. http://jsbin.com/isodas/5/edit

Comment: See my update and JS Bin Link. It is a little bit verbose, but i think that there were name clashing issues, because index maybe should not be a Resource?

Comment: Is it possible to have the "main" route render the "sign_in" route's content *without* having the `transitionTo` replace the url? Meaning that the base url (`/`) and the sign_in url (`/sign_in`) would render the exact same content.